# authentication for git remote push to github

Tags: git, https, github

Github says they prefer https over ssh. Does this mean I should do something like this on my local machine:

```
git romote add github 'https://userid:passwd@github.com/userid/repo.git'
```

If so is sending a password in an https url safe? I have already tried the following:

```
git remote add github 'https://github.com/userid/repo.git'
git push github master
```

It says `authentication failed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending the password over HTTPS is safe (banking, credit cards, login, etc. are all done over HTTPS for this reason).

However, depending on how git stores the URL, the password may be exposed in plain text to anyone who has access to your local repository.